# How can I highlight a Listview item on MouseHover event in VB.net?

Tags: vb.net, listview

How can I highlight a `Listview` item on `MouseHover` event in VB.net,
just like windows explorer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the `HoverSelection` property of your `ListView` control to `True`.  However, if you want it to be selected immediately, you can implement it manually.  For instance, you could try something like this:

```
Private Sub ListView1_MouseMove(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles ListView1.MouseMove
    Dim currentItem As ListViewItem = ListView1.GetItemAt(e.X, e.Y)
    For Each item As ListViewItem In ListView1.Items
        item.Selected = False
    Next
    If currentItem IsNot Nothing Then
        currentItem.Selected = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Make sure, though, that the `HideSelection` property on the `ListView` control is set to `False`, otherwise the selection will not be shown unless the list has the focus.

Comment: But HoverSelection property selects item after some delay.I want instant selection.

Comment: @VijayJadhav Then you should specify that in your question.

Answer (score 0):

without flickering:

```
Private Sub ListView1_MouseMove(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles ListView1.MouseMove
    Dim currentItem As ListViewItem = ListView1.GetItemAt(e.X, e.Y)
    For Each item As ListViewItem In ListView1.Items
        If currentItem IsNot Nothing Then
            currentItem.Selected = True
        Else
            item.Selected = False
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```